# Centering text inside a div column

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using the Zurb Foundation framework and am trying to center text.

If I just use the `.text-center` class:

`<h1 class="text-center">My Heading</h1>` The text is center.

However, when I place it inside a column, the text is moved slightly to the right:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 small-centered columns text-center">
        <h1>My Heading</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to ask what is the correct way of centering the text inside columns?

Comment: I would suspect there's other CSS acting on it if it's going to the right, is there? Otherwise you would just use `.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 1):

its should work fine with your code , but if you can provide screenshot to see what do u mean by its move to the right will be nice.

anyway check this solution may work , and the issue could be from additional custom css added if u have one .

**CSS :**

```
  .row h1 { margin: 0 auto; padding : 0px }
```

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqcobex4/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the word inside the heading is too long for my mobile device so I added the style property:

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Not sure if this is the correct way to handle such cases but it is a possible solution.